# Dynamic Component Loader - How to register Components from different modules?

Tags: angular

I'm implementing an Angular app that consists of several modules:
- app module
- shared modules
- core module
- different customer modules

The solution is highly dynamically. A DynamicComponentLoader should create my components. I followed the approach described here: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Question: The problem is, I’m not sure how to register all my components because they are located in different modules.

[image]

SharedModule:

```
...
/**
 * Implements "forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders"
 * to register all Services in the Root Injector.
 */
@NgModule({
  imports: imports,
  providers: [DynamicComponentService],
  declarations: declarations,
  exports: componentsToExport,
  entryComponents: componentsDynamic,
})
export class SharedModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: SharedModule,
      providers: providers
    };
  }
```

DynamicComponentService

```
export class DynamicComponentService {

  private dynamicComponents: DynamicComponentDescriptor[] = [];

  constructor() { }

  public addComponents(components: DynamicComponentDescriptor[]) {
    this.dynamicComponents = this.dynamicComponents.concat(components);
  }
  ...
}
```

DynamicComponentBuilderComponent

```
export class DynamicComponentBuilderComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() elementConfig: IElementConfig[];
  @ViewChild(DynamicComponentPlaceholderDirective, { static: true }) placeholder: DynamicComponentPlaceholderDirective;

  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.elementConfig);
    // elementConfig contains the component name to create
     ...

    // The ComponentFactory creates an instance of the corresponding component
    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(???);

    // ComponentPlaceholderDirective injects ViewContainerRef into its constructor.
    // This is how the directive accesses the element that you want to use to host the dynamic component.
    const viewContainerRef = this.placeholder.viewContainerRef;
    viewContainerRef.clear();

    // To add the component to the template, you call createComponent() on ViewContainerRef.
    // The createComponent() method returns a reference to the loaded component.
    // Use that reference to interact with the component by assigning to its properties or calling its methods.
    const componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
    // (<AdComponent>componentRef.instance).data = adItem.data;
  }
}
```

Comment: You can give your modules a constructor, and call a method on the service to register the components. It's honestly the easiest approach.

Comment: Thank you, that worked!